# Mysterious 500 Error with Basic Rails App on Slicehost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, ubuntu-8.10, slicehost

I am getting a mysterious 500 error when i try to deploy my first rails app on slicehost.

I have followed the Ubuntu Intrepid articles very closely and it seems to be all setup accordingly.

I am trying to run rails on Apache with Passenger. All I am trying to run here is a basic rails app with one scaffold (3 fields).

The apache error log product is meaningless to me:
[Fri Aug 21 06:51:25 2009] [debug] mod_deflate.c(619): [client 76.64.149.210] Zlib: Compressed 948 to 567 : URL /articles

No other errors are being thrown.

Please help me get this basic app working.

Thanks,

Chris Homer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be a basic mistake.  I had run "db:migrate" but only in development.  had not run it in production.